# A vector that contains other vectors that contain pointers to dynamic objects

Tags: c++

I have a number of objects that I create dynamically. These objects are defined globally.

```
    Object *obj1 = new Object;
    Object *obj2 = new Object;
    Object *obj3 = new Object;
```

I also have a vector that will store all of these objects.

```
    std::vector<Object*> cntr;
    cntr.push_back(obj1);
    cntr.push_back(obj2);
    cntr.push_back(obj3);
```

I create a few other vectors exactly like the one above and populate these with similar objects.

```
    std::vector<Object*> cntr2;
    std::vector<Object*> cntr3;
```

If I want to access any of the member functions of any of those objects I can simply write this:

```
    cntr[i]->memberFunction();
    cntr2[i]->memberFunction();
```

However, later in my code I create a vector to store similar vectors of type Object*

```
    std::vector< std::vector<Object*> > GroupCntr;
    GroupCntr.push_back(cntr);
    GroupCntr.push_back(cntr2);
```

The problem I am now faced with is how to access the member functions of the objects stored in the vectors that are stored in GroupCntr? I have tried every combination of

```
    *    ->   ()   []   (*)
```

with no success. I am also aware that I might be criticised for this kind of code, as it relies heavily on the use of raw pointers and brings into question the subject of ownership. However I would really like to know how this exercise can be achieved?

Comment: `GroupCntr[outer_index][inner_index]->object_member;`

Comment: All you need to know is how to access an element of a vector. That's it. Just think about it a little.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get element you need to use `'[][]'`
the first `[]` is to access to vector,
the second `[]` is to access to element.

Next to get access to element you need use '->' operator

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct sample {
 int p;
};


int main () {

  std::vector<sample*> vec_sample;
  std::vector<sample*> vec_sample1;

  sample* sample1 = new sample();
  sample1->p=6;
  sample* sample2 = new sample();
  sample2->p=2;
  vec_sample.push_back(sample1);
  vec_sample.push_back(sample2);
  std::vector<std::vector<sample*> > many;
  many.push_back(vec_sample);
  many.push_back(vec_sample1);
  std::cout<<many[0][0]->p<<std::endl;

}
```

Comment: you should demonstrate how the [][]-> combination work in your answer, instead of using ints, as the OP uses pointers for the vector type